# Analyze all uppercase tokens in a field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I would like to analyze value of a text field in 2 ways. Using standard analysis and a custom analysis that only indexes all uppercase tokens in the text.

For example, if the value is "This WHITE cat is very CUTE.", the only tokens that should be indexed for custom analysis is "WHITE" and "CUTE". For this, I am using [Pattern Capture Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html) with pattern "(\b[A-Z]+\b)+?". But this is indexing all tokens and not just uppercase tokens.

Is Pattern Capture Token Filter the right one to use for this task? If yes, what am I doing wrong? If not, how do I get this done? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use instead pattern_replace and char_filter:

```html
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "filter_lowercase": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "[A-Z][a-z]+|[a-z]+",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "filter_lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET test/_analyze
{"analyzer": "my_analyzer", 
  "text" : "This WHITE cat is very CUTE"
}
```